# How would I best simplify this segment of code>includes valueErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Disclaimer: noob here. I am currently studying Python in college, and code not only at school, but for fun. I am currently writing a planet generating code (which I fully wrote in smallbasic language) and working it into Python language. I am running into a slight problem, due to the inexperience I have with Python, but this may be an easy one for you guys. Please tell me how exactly I can improve this segment of code so it works in the simplest way possible. Also, I want to point out that I want the user to enter a number between 1 and 12 planets to generate. Also, if the user just presses `ENTER`, enters a number outside the 1-12 number range, or enters anything other than a number, I'm wanting the program to just pick a random number. The code below works how I want it too, but it just looks sloppy and overkill...

```
def num_planets():
    try:
        valid = ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
        count = int(input("How many planets would you like to generate? "))
        if count != valid:
            import random
            count = random.randint(1,12)
            print("Given the invalid user input, the random valid integer,",count,"was selected.")
    except ValueError:
        import random
        count = random.randint(1,12)
        print("Given the invalid user input, the random valid integer,",count,"was selected.")

num_planets()
```

Comment: correction* the code above does not work. It always says input is invalid even when I chose a number between 1 and 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think it's working the way you expect it to because `count != valid` is comparing an `int` to a `tuple` of strings. So that condition will always be `True` (so your code will always generate a random value).

You need to convert `valid` into a `tuple` of ints, then use the [`in` operation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) to check if the `int` value is part of the `tuple`.

Like this:

```
valid = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
count = int(input("How many planets would you like to generate? "))
if count not in valid:
    # use a random value
```

Second, to avoid repetition, you could place the randomizer code in a method.

Like this:

```
def use_random_value():
    import random
    count = random.randint(1, 12)
    print("Given the invalid user input, the random valid integer,", count, "was selected.")


def num_planets():
    try:
        valid = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
        count = int(input("How many planets would you like to generate? "))
        if count not in valid:
            use_random_value()
    except ValueError:
        use_random_value()


num_planets()
```

Lastly, the `try/catch` for the `int(..)` is already "simple" enough as it follows the EAFP [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) pattern. It will clearly try to convert the input value to an `int`, then you can just easily handle the error if that fails.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you Gino. I did not know you could include the NOT boolean logic into an IN operation. Now that I think of it, it makes sense:/

Comment: No problem :) By the way, I forgot to mention [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) as a coding style, which is implemented by that `try/catch` code.